# Upload stream to Dropbox session upload

Tags: node.js, dropbox

I have a form that accepts a file to pass on to Dropbox using the session upload. I've wrapped the code in a Fastify server but always end up with an error in append:

```
{"error_summary": "closed/..", "error": {".tag": "closed"}}.
```

Here's the Fastify server:

```
require("dotenv").config()
const https = require("https")
const JSONbig = require("json-bigint")

const TOKEN = process.env.DROPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN

const fastify = require("fastify")({
  logger: {
    level: "info"
  }
})

fastify.addContentTypeParser("*", function (req, done) {
  done()
})

// Promisify https request
const httpRequest = (url, options, data) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.request(url, options, (res) => {
      let body = ""
      res.on("data", (chunk) => {
        console.log("SDSDSDSDASDASDSAD")
        body += chunk.toString()
      })
      res.on("error", reject)
      res.on("end", () => {
        if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode <= 299) {
          resolve({ statusCode: res.statusCode, headers: res.headers, body: JSON.parse(body) })
        } else {
          reject("Request failed. status: " + res.statusCode + ", body: " + body)
        }
      })
    })
    req.on("error", reject)
    if (data) req.write(data)
    req.end()
  })
}

fastify.register(require("fastify-cors"))

fastify.post("/", async (req, reply) => {
  const stream = req.raw

  const initResponse = await httpRequest(
    "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload_session/start",
    {
      method: "post",

      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
        "Dropbox-API-Arg": JSON.stringify({
          close: false
        }),
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
      }
    }
  )

  const sessionId = initResponse.body.session_id

  req.log.info(`Initiating session ${sessionId}`)

  let offset = 0

  stream.on("data", async (chunk) => {
    req.log.info("Sending chunk")
    stream.pause()

    const appendResponse = await httpRequest(
      `https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload_session/append_v2`,

      {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
          "Dropbox-API-Arg": JSONbig.stringify({
            cursor: {
              session_id: sessionId,
              offset
            },
            close: false
          }),
          "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
        }
      },
      chunk
    )

    stream.resume()
    offset += chunk.length
  })
  stream.on("end", async () => {
    const terminateResponse = await httpRequest(
      `https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload_session/finish`,

      {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
          "Dropbox-API-Arg": JSONbig.stringify({
            cursor: {
              session_id: sessionId,
              offset: offset
            },
            commit: {
              path: "/Upload/test-large.txt",
              mode: "add",
              autorename: true,
              mute: false,
              strict_conflict: false
            }
          }),
          "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
        }
      }
    )

    req.log.info("upload session finished")

    reply.code(204).send()
  })
})

fastify.listen(3000, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    fastify.log.fatal(err)
    process.exit(1)
  }
  console.log(`server listening on ${fastify.server.address().port}`)
})
```

And here's the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Coding By CodingNepal - youtube.com/codingnepal -->
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>File Upload with Progress Bar | CodingNepal</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <style>
      /* Import Google font - Poppins */
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap");
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
      }
      body {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        min-height: 100vh;
        background: #6990f2;
      }

      ::selection {
        color: #fff;
        background: #6990f2;
      }
      .wrapper {
        width: 430px;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 30px;
        box-shadow: 7px 7px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
      }
      .wrapper header {
        color: #6990f2;
        font-size: 27px;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .wrapper form {
        height: 167px;
        display: flex;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 30px 0;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px dashed #6990f2;
      }
      form :where(i, p) {
        color: #6990f2;
      }
      form i {
        font-size: 50px;
      }
      form p {
        margin-top: 15px;
        font-size: 16px;
      }

      section .row {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        background: #e9f0ff;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
      section .row i {
        color: #6990f2;
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      section .details span {
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      .progress-area .row .content {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 15px;
      }
      .progress-area .details {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin-bottom: 7px;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
      .progress-area .content .progress-bar {
        height: 6px;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 30px;
      }
      .content .progress-bar .progress {
        height: 100%;
        width: 0%;
        background: #6990f2;
        border-radius: inherit;
      }
      .uploaded-area {
        max-height: 232px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
      .uploaded-area.onprogress {
        max-height: 150px;
      }
      .uploaded-area::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 0px;
      }
      .uploaded-area .row .content {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .uploaded-area .row .details {
        display: flex;
        margin-left: 15px;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .uploaded-area .row .details .size {
        color: #404040;
        font-size: 11px;
      }
      .uploaded-area i.fa-check {
        font-size: 16px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header>File Uploader JavaScript</header>
      <form action="#">
        <input class="file-input" type="file" name="file" hidden />
        <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i>
        <p>Browse File to Upload</p>
      </form>
      <section class="progress-area"></section>
      <section class="uploaded-area"></section>
    </div>
    <script>
      const form = document.querySelector("form"),
        fileInput = document.querySelector(".file-input"),
        progressArea = document.querySelector(".progress-area"),
        uploadedArea = document.querySelector(".uploaded-area")

      // form click event
      form.addEventListener("click", () => {
        fileInput.click()
      })

      fileInput.onchange = ({ target }) => {
        let file = target.files[0] //getting file [0] this means if user has selected multiple files then get first one only
        if (file) {
          let fileName = file.name //getting file name
          if (fileName.length >= 12) {
            //if file name length is greater than 12 then split it and add ...
            let splitName = fileName.split(".")
            fileName = splitName[0].substring(0, 13) + "... ." + splitName[1]
          }
          uploadFile(fileName) //calling uploadFile with passing file name as an argument
        }
      }

      // file upload function
      function uploadFile(name) {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest() //creating new xhr object (AJAX)
        xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000") //sending post request to the specified URL
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", ({ loaded, total }) => {
          //file uploading progress event
          let fileLoaded = Math.floor((loaded / total) * 100) //getting percentage of loaded file size
          let fileTotal = Math.floor(total / 1000) // getting total file size in KB from bytes
          let fileSize
          // if file size is less than 1024 then add only KB else convert this KB into MB
          fileTotal < 1024
            ? (fileSize = fileTotal + " KB")
            : (fileSize = (loaded / (1024 * 1024)).toFixed(2) + " MB")
          let progressHTML = `<li class="row">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>
                            <div class="content">
                              <div class="details">
                                <span class="name">${name} • Uploading</span>
                                <span class="percent">${fileLoaded}%</span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="progress-bar">
                                <div class="progress" style="width: ${fileLoaded}%"></div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </li>`
          // uploadedArea.innerHTML = ""; //uncomment this line if you don't want to show upload history
          uploadedArea.classList.add("onprogress")
          progressArea.innerHTML = progressHTML
          if (loaded == total) {
            progressArea.innerHTML = ""
            let uploadedHTML = `<li class="row">
                              <div class="content upload">
                                <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>
                                <div class="details">
                                  <span class="name">${name} • Uploaded</span>
                                  <span class="size">${fileSize}</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                            </li>`
            uploadedArea.classList.remove("onprogress")
            // uploadedArea.innerHTML = uploadedHTML; //uncomment this line if you don't want to show upload history
            uploadedArea.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", uploadedHTML) //remove this line if you don't want to show upload history
          }
        })
        let data = new FormData(form) //FormData is an object to easily send form data
        xhr.send(data) //sending form data
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does need an app created on DB to get oauth token to run example.

Anyone see the issue here? I've worked from a number of examples online but all of them assume I am using some dummy static file rather than incoming uploaded file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out. Basically in my example I am terminating the session on `end` but it turns out the `end` event is fired at the same time as the last `data` event so I am effectively closing the session in the midst of the last chunk append. I refactored things to have a flag `isEnd` that gets set in the `end` event handler and moved the terminate session and resolve code inside of the `data` handler to be fired from there once `isEnd` is set.